# Регулярное выражение для строки из цифр и минуса

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нубский вопросик, просто незнаю регулярки: требуется регулярка которая допускает только цифры от 0 до 9 и символ -  (минус)

Answer (score 1):

Если минус может встречаться несколько раз:

```
[-0-9]+
```

Если минус всегда в начале

```
-?[0-9]+
```

Comment: во втором варианте минус получается обязательным. Может, лучше

    -?[0-9]+

Comment: @sergiks Да, спасибо.